# Inverse of a function

Tags: functions, exponential-function, lambert-w

How can we find the inverse of $f(x) = 3x + e^{2x} $?

I am not able to separate the $x$ even taking the logarithm on both sides.

Comment: It probably can't be expressed using elementary functions.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=find+x+in+y+%3D+3x+%2B+e%5E%7B2x%7D

Answer (score 1):

It can't be expressed using elementary functions.

In future use [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=find+x+in+y+%3D+3x+%2B+e%5E%7B2x%7D) $$x = \frac16 \left(2y - 3W_n\left(\frac23e^{2y/3}\right)\right)$$